# Populate an existing XLSX from TXT format file using VBScript

Tags: excel, vbscript

I need to populate an existing **XLSX format file** from six **TXT format files**.

On the **XLSX format file** there are names of the predefined columns.

The **TXT format files** are delimited with the *pipe* | *symbol*.

I need to skip the first two lines of each TXT file.

I tried this code, and the error I get is:

> VBscript error input past end of file

```
 ArrE = Array("D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5", "D6")

 For I = 0 To UBound(ArrE)

   Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\" & ArrE(I) & "_A3.txt", ForReading)

   objTextFile.ReadAll
   lineCount = objTextFile.Line
   objTextFile.Close

   Set objTextFile2 = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\" & ArrE(I) & "_A3.txt", ForReading)

   i = 0
   while i < lineCount
     objTextFile2.ReadLine
     i = i+1
   wend

   Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
   objExcel.Application.Visible = True
   Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\PAB_A3_def_REV01.xlsx")
   Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

   j = 1
   Do Until objTextFile2.AtEndOfStream
     line = objTextFile2.ReadLine
     objWorksheet.Cells(1, j).Value =  line
     j=j+1
   Loop  

 Next
```

**Update #01**

```
ArrE = Array("D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5", "D6")

 For I = 0 To UBound(ArrE)

   Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\" & ArrE(I) & "_A3.txt", ForReading)

   objTextFile.ReadAll
   lineCount = objTextFile.Line
   objTextFile.Close

   Set objTextFile2 = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\" & ArrE(I) & "_A3.txt", ForReading)

   i = 0
   while i < lineCount -1
     objTextFile2.ReadLine
     i = i+1
   wend

   Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
   objExcel.Application.Visible = True
   Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\PAB_A3_def_REV01.xlsx")
   Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

   j = 1
   Do Until objTextFile2.AtEndOfStream
     line = objTextFile2.ReadLine
     objWorksheet.Cells(1, j).Value =  line
     j=j+1
   Loop  

 Next
```

Comment: Does the last line of your file end with a CrLf ? (check with a proper editor, like notepad2 or npp)

Comment: Open the TXT as normal workbook, delete the first 2 rows, and then copy/paste

Comment: don't  understand why trying to iterate through lines of `objTextFile2` twice.  2nd loop may fail as pointer already reaches End of steam. Also  try changing line `while i < lineCount`  to `while i < lineCount - 1` as i was initialized as 0.

Comment: @AhmedAU Many thanks for help, please see **Update #01** in my first question. Now I don't have error on the script but the XLSX file is empty.

Comment: The excel file is empty as 2nd iteration of `objTextFile2` is not working as pointer had already reached End of file during 1st iteration ( I think 1st loop is doing nothing). Posting an answer with some assumption about how the data is to be arranged in the target Xlsx file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is based on the assumption how the data is to be arranged in the target xlsx file. May please modify it to your requirement.

Assumptions:

1. The code is run from a vbscript (vbs) file.
2. The Data from 3rd line onwards to the last line from each file is arrangend in rows in target file, the next text file’s  data is to placed below the last row
3. The data from  each line is to be split with the delimiter | and spread across columns starting from 1

Issues modified:

1. The target file is to be opened once only. So the open statement moved out of the Loop
2. Find no need to iterate / read multiple times. So singe iteration is used to collect the data, stating from 3rd line onward.

Modified Code:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
ArrE = Array("D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5", "D6")
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Application.Visible = True
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\PAB_A3_def_REV01.xlsx")
Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Rw = 0
 For i = 0 To UBound(ArrE)
   Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\" & ArrE(i) & "_A3.txt", 1) 'ForReading)
   j = 1
   Do Until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
     Line = objTextFile.ReadLine
        If j > 2 Then        
        arr = Split(Line, "|")

              If UBound(arr) >= 0 Then
              Rw = Rw + 1
              End if

            For col = 0 To UBound(arr)
            objWorksheet.Cells(Rw, col + 1).Value = arr(col)
            Next 
        End If
     j = j + 1
   Loop
 objTextFile.close
 Next
```

Script tested with makeshift data. Feel free to contact in case of problem.